# Splitting disjunctions (\/) in Coq hypothesis

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove a simple lemma in Coq where **the hypothesis is a disjunction**. I know how to `split` disjunctions when they occur in the goal,
but can't manage to split them when they appear in the hypothesis. Here is my example:

```
Theorem splitting_disjunctions_in_hypotheses : forall (n : nat),
  ((n < 5) \/ (n > 8)) -> ((n > 7) \/ (n < 6)).
Proof.
  intros n H1.
  split H1. (** this doesn't work ... *)
```

And here is what Coq says:

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
H1 : n < 5 \/ n > 8
______________________________________(1/1)
n > 7 \/ n < 6
```

With error:

```
Error: Illegal tactic application.
```

I'm clearly missing something simple.
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tactic you want is [`destruct`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.destruct).

```
Theorem splitting_disjunctions_in_hypotheses : forall (n : nat),
  ((n < 5) \/ (n > 8)) -> ((n > 7) \/ (n < 6)).
Proof.
  intros n H1.
  destruct H1.
```

If you want to name the resulting hypotheses you can do `destruct H1 as [name1 | name2].`.